# Preciso ler o nome de uma pasta em C#

Tags: c#, diretório

Como eu consigo ler o nome de uma pasta?
Preciso entrar em um diretorio e ler o nome de uma pasta

ex: "\C:\ACBrMonitorPLUS\NFe\" + (o nome da pasta que esta dentro da pasta NFE)

o nome da pasta eh fixo, que se trata de um CNPJ da empresa no qual esta intalado o programa e retornar o nome da pasta para uma variavel

Comment: isso ajuda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode percorrer os sub-diretórios dentro da pasta `root`.

```
var dirRoot = "C:\\ACBrMonitorPLUS\\NFe\\";
string[] subDiretorios = Directory.GetDirectories(dirRoot);
           
subDiretorios.ToList().ForEach(d => {Console.WriteLine(d)});
```

Na mesma linha de pensamento pode percorrer os arquivos

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(dirRoot, "PASTADOCNPJ");
fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath , "*.xml");
```

Veja também:

a [documentação oficial da MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-6.0) sobre `GetDirectories`

a [documentação oficial da MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0) sobre `GetFiles`

Comment: excelente amigo, deu super certo aqui, muito obrigado

Comment: Show! marque a resposta como aceita, para ajudar as outras pessoas.